# Swift, iOS. How to build custom URL class to return data from specific storage

Tags: swift

I have the App where on class requests URL to read a file. I can overload the function that returns URL.
Instead of local file or http url i want to return data that are stored in SQLite DB.

My code is like

```
class MyClass: BaseClass {
  override func url(x:Int, y:Int) -> URL {
    let url =
      "https://someserver.com/\(x)/\(y).png"
    return URL(string: tileUrl)!
  }
}
```

This is the original code, it loads a file from web.

But i have that data cached in SQLite DB locally in the smartphone. I want to load data from it. So, i need a way somehow to redirect URL reading to my custom code.
Is it possible?

Maybe some kind of class created over URL

```
class MyCustomUrl:URL {
    override func ... something ...
}
```

Or maybe it is possible to build custom local url scheme? Like
let url =
"myscheme://anything/(x)/(y).png"
And somewhere i have to register "myscheme" to work internally in this app?

What are possible ways to do this in Swift?

Comment: [This article](https://www.appcoda.com/core-data-preload-sqlite-database/) may have what you want.

Comment: No. That is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, i have found the solution myself.

The idea is to use the "data:" url scheme with URL class

```
let data:Data = //... get your file data, NOTE, care about big size files
let base64String = data!.base64EncodedString()

let imgURIPath = "data:image/png;base64,\(base64String)"
// content type is related to your file data type
return URL(string: imgURIPath)!
```

This works for me